# Personal email addresses are not allowed. Please use a corporate email address in Google partner training website?

Tags: email, gmail

I don't know about corporate email address.
how to create a Google corporate email address and use like a mail .because i want to sign up to Google partner training website not allow to sign in with simple mail id . so can you suggest alternative options to join the training.

Comment: Please add more information. Are you employee of a company or an individual? Why do you need a corporate email address? Are you trying to sign up to a specific service?

Comment: I need because Google partner training website not allow to sign in with simple mail id

Comment: This is an important detail. Now edit your post and tell you want to sign up to Google parthner training. Maybe people here can suggest alternative options to join the training. More relevant details can help to answer your question the best possible way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to Google Account Creation page[1]
2. Enter your first and last name
3. Under your email address,enter your corporate email address(for example,
   you@yourcompany.com).Important: Don't create a personal gmail address.
4. If the username field is prefilled with @gmail.com, delete this and enter your
   company email address.
5. Create a password for your google account,enter your personal information,and
   click Next.
6. On the verify your email page, enter the code you receive from Google at your
   company email address and click Verify. It takes time to get the verification
   email.
7. Enter your phone number and click Next.
8. Enter the code you get on your phone and click Next.
9. Enter your birthday, select your gender and click Next.
10. Review and check the Privacy and Terms boxes, then click Create
    Account.
    Click Confirm.

Go to Partner training page[2] and click on register as a new portal user and sign up with the ID you just created.

[1]https://accounts.google.com
[2]https://www.partneradvantage.goog/GCPPRM/s/partneradvantageportallogin?language=en_US